# IIS Redirect non-www to www AND http to https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

i'm trying to implement two rules for IIS to Redirect non-WWW to WWW and http to https.

```
http://zzz.com -> https://www.zzz.com
http://www.zzz.com -> https://www.zzz.com
https://zzz.com -> https://www.zzz.com
```

So, i added this to my web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <rules>
    <rule name="Force WWW" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.zzz.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.zzz.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

My Question:

Is there any way to combine this in one rule?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes you can merge them into one and use the logicalGrouping for the conditions and set it to Any which would be the equivalent of an "OR". For example:

```
<rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.zzz.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi when I try this for my own problem win 2012 IIS 8 when I try to go to https://example.com/ then it errors. http://example.com goes to https://www.example.com and example.com but https://example.com just takes me to a This site can’t be reached

example.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
Try:
Reloading the page
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy, firewall and DNS configuration
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: I have 4 bindings setup by the way 1 with www for http and https and one without www

Comment: You do need 4 bindings. IIS needs a binding for each "bad" version of the domain as well as the preferred domain.  e.g. 
`http://zzz.com, https://zzz.com, http://www.zzz.com, https://www.zzz.com`.

Comment: @carlos: how would you make the domain name in this example dynamic and preserve that in the redirect? I want to use your example, but I now have this condition: `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />` and this action `<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />` help is appreciated!

Comment: @PhilM the binding reminder is primo.  It's easy for me to forget this.

Comment: @MonkeyMagix your answer is working, but is there any solution via url rewriting ? because there is problem with https://example.com when you bind website with "www"