# Web.config : force HTTPS and WWW with VARIABLE domain name

Tags: iis, web-config

I've seen a lot of answers that come close, like this one: [IIS Redirect non-www to www AND http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490426/iis-redirect-non-www-to-www-and-http-to-https) but it's does not exactly match my case.

I have a website that has 2 domain aliases on top of its main domain name. Displaying the right content for each version is done in the code itself.

I am trying to use the WEB.CONFIG file to rewrite in 2 cases: when HTTPS is not used and/or when WWW is absent at the beginning of the url.

So http://example.com, https://example.com and http://www.example.com would all be rewritten as https://www.example.com   Same thing if the site is visited using one of its domain aliases, for example http://examplealias.com would become https://www.examplealias.com

This answer

```
<rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" negate="true" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

will not work for me as I cannot hard code the domain name.

I have tried this

```
<rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" negate="true" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

but this results in https://www.www.example.com if I call http://www.example.com

What would be the right way to combine both conditions?

Comment: remove the `www.` in your redirect. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53341759/9936356

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently in my case, it's better NOT to combine the rules:

```
    <rule name="Redirect naked domains (that do NOT have a custom sub-domain) to www.domain.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www." negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect non-https urls to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

This works perfectly.